# Construct generator function from array

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, generator, yield

I am trying to build a generator function from an array. The simplest example would be:

```
    const array = [1,2,3,4]

    function * createGenerator () {
        array.map(function(elem){
            yield elem
        }
    }
```

And I would expect:

```
function * createGenerator () {
        yield 1
        yield 2
        yield 3
        yield 4
    }
```

Also if I want to add a switch statement like this:

```
function processServerActions (array) {
    for (let elem in array) {
        switch(elem) {
            case 1:
                yield 1111
            case 2:
                yield 22222
            case 3:
                yield 333333
                yield 444444
            case 4:
                yield 55555
        }
    }

}
```

But is not working. What am I missing?

Thanks!

Comment: several syntax errors pop out...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The callback can only return the callback. For yielding the generator function, the `yield` has to be inside of the function, but outside of a nested callback.

Better you use `for ... of` for yielding a value.

```js
function* createGenerator() {
    for (let elem of array){
        yield elem;
    }
}  

const array = [1,2,3,4],
      c = createGenerator();

console.log([...c]);
```

You need `for (let elem of array)` with `of` instead of `in`.

```js
function* createGenerator() {
    for (let elem of array) {
        switch(elem) {
            case 1:
                yield 1111;
                break;
            case 2:
                yield 22222;
                break;
            case 3:
                yield 333333;
                yield 444444;
                break;
            case 4:
                yield 55555;
        }
    }
}

const array = [1,2,3,4],
      c = createGenerator();

console.log([...c]);
```

Comment: Great, and if I would want to add a switch statement, to yield some other thing depending on the number I am getting from the array? (I edited the question to show more details about this)